# getting error reading the excel file in flutter web

Tags: flutter, spreadsheet, xlsx, flutter-web, openxlsx

here is my code it's printing the encrypted data

```
ht.InputElement File = ht.FileUploadInputElement();
      File.click();
      File.onChange.listen((event) {
        final file = File.files.first;
        final reader = ht.FileReader();
        var a = file.name;
        if(a.contains('.xlsx')) {
          reader.onLoadEnd.listen((event) {
            var decoder = SpreadsheetDecoder.decodeBytes(reader.result);
            var table = decoder.tables['Sheet 1'];
            var values = table.rows[0];
            print(values);
          });
        }
```

output

```
js_primitives.dart:47 [� [!��Ov�!���%������L�vo���W�FΓ���"�8\��(2z�
```

I want to print the data at row 0
can anyone help me in this

Answer (score 0):

Okh so I solved it finally just need to add

```
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

before reader.onLoadEnd